# What can PointCloud2 store?

Tags: pcl, sensor-msgs, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the pcl and need to pass over some normals with a point cloud (ie pcl::PointXYZRGBNormal points) to a service. Therefore I would like to know if the PointCloud2 can hold all this information (I now it is quite flexible).
More generally and because I think I might not be the only beginner wondering about:
What can PointCloud2 store ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9458/what-can-pointcloud2-store-?/) by [Captain](https://answers.ros.org/users/112/captain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well I finally found myself, I had not see this
http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html

> This message holds a collection of
> N-dimensional points, which may
> contain additional information such as
> normals, intensity, etc. The point
> data is stored as a binary blob, its
> layout described by the contents of
> the "fields" array.
>
> The point cloud data may be organized
> 2d (image-like) or 1d (unordered).
> Point clouds organized as 2d images
> may be produced by camera depth
> sensors such as stereo or
> time-of-flight.

---

Originally posted by [Captain](https://answers.ros.org/users/112/captain/) with karma: 88 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that you can publish/subscribe to `pcl::PointCloud` types directly using [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros); no need to write your own conversion to/from `PointCloud2`. `PointCloud2` and `pcl::PointCloud` were designed in tandem, so in general `PointCloud2` can hold any data expressible as a `pcl::PointCloud` and vice versa.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-04-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2